# How long would this take to bruteforce?

Tags: brute-force, python, burp-suite, code-review, ctf

I am working on the following war game from **Defend The Web**, which requires me to do a source code review to login as the user `memtash`. The code is on GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/DefendTheWeb/foss-login/-/blob/master/class.user.php).

Having inspected the source code during this code review, I find this line interesting:

```
$token = md5(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
```

The output of the `md5()` function in PHP is:

```
 - Always 32 characters
 - Lowercase
 - Hexadecimal format (0-9, a-f)
```

My plan is to request a password reset for the user `memtash` on the webpage, and then bruteforce through every possible combination, following the above rules. Eventually, one combination will bring me to the password reset screen.

I was wondering how long it would take an average consumer computer to brute force this token? I was planning to write a Python script, but it is likely Burpsuite can already do this.

Comment: Note that the output of the PHP `md5()` function is something of a red herring here, because the output as described is really the hexadecimal string encoding of a bunch of raw bytes.  ie, it's not actually randomly picking `1e`, but instead has generated the byte pattern `00011110`.

Comment: Having looked at the code on gitlab, there is a **major** security bug in the way `login()` and `reset()` are coded in combination with each other.  Due to this bug, it also creates a user experience problem as well...  You don't actually need to worry about the token, the solution is much simpler than that.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yeah I figured it out, if you look at the question I posted after this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long it takes to bruteforce something depend on a couple factors: if the attack is offline (where the attacker have the hash and bruteforces it) or online (the attacker sends data to the server and receives responses back), the hash type, the number of iterations.

It is not clear from your question if you are trying to get the password from the hash, or you are sending the hash to the server.

If you have the hash and want the password, and you are doing it on your machine, it will heavily depend on how fast you can feed data to MD5. The output of MD5 is 2<sup>128</sup>, and that's a large number.

If the attack is online, it's usually not feasible to bruteforce a hash. Even if you can send a million tries per second, it's still too little to get a collision on a 2<sup>128</sup> output space.

Even if you are just trying to "forge" the token (it's a hash of 32 bytes), it will still take too much time to do online (I mean several thousand centuries).

So if this is a CTF, you need to find another route.

Comment: It is an online attack, sending the hash to the server.

Comment: Any ideas what else I could try, it seems vulnerable to SQL injection since there is no sanitising, but I am stuck.